# Multiple Http calls in one @ngrx/effect

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx, angular12

I am very confused, and new to @ngrx so please forgive me for not understanding how this is supposed to work.

Let's say I have an effect that is called `PlaceOrderEffect`

In this effect, I want to process each request in order.

```
processOrder$ = createEffect(
   ofType(OrderActions.PROCESS_ORDER),
   //here is where i get confused
   concatMap([
      this.service.addCrust(),
      this.service.addTopings(),
      this.service.sendToCook()
      this.service.checkOut()
   ]
)
```

How can I run these in sequential order and handle the final response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`concatMap` is `RxJS` operator to be used with `pipe`, to merge the source observable with the new one returned by `concatMap`, which is not your case.

I think you can use `RxJS` `concat` function to achieve what you're trying to do if the requests don't depend on each other, like the following:

```js
processOrder$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(OrderActions.PROCESS_ORDER),
        // here you need to switch and map to the new observable (concat one) returned by switchMapTo operator
        switchMap(({ payload }) =>
            concat(
                this.service.addCrust(),
                this.service.addTopings(),
                this.service.sendToCook(),
                this.service.checkOut()
            )
        )
    )
);
```

But if each request depends on the previous one, you can use `concatMap` operator like the following:

```js
processOrder$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(OrderActions.PROCESS_ORDER),
        concatMap(({ payload }) => this.service.addCrust(payload)),
        concatMap((response1) => this.service.addTopings(response1)),
        concatMap((response2) => this.service.sendToCook(response2)),
        concatMap((response3) => this.service.checkOut(response3))
    )
);
```

Comment: exhaustMap does here more sense for haven't multiply calls by trigger the action

Comment: This answer is wrong. An effect is supposed to map to only one action. In the proposed solution not only are we not mapping to an action, we're issuing multiple HTTP calls directly in a service, which is discouraged.